# Double-click JavaScript files in KDE Dolphin and open in editor instead of trying to execute

Tags: kde, kubuntu, dolphin

I've been searching for an embarassingly long time without finding a solution for this. Having to right-click files all day would be an exceedingly miserable experience. Is there any way to fix this?

Specifically we get the following error:
[image]

Comment: Is *<right click> Open with →Other application <select application> <mark> Remember application association...* what you are looking for?

Comment: Sadly no. Even after applying that setting, the files continue to try to open as executables.

Comment: *Dolphin preferences → General → Confirmations → When open executable file → open in application*?

Comment: Thank you so much, that's a huge help! I wish there was a way to have it apply only to `.js` files and not all executables, but close enough! (PS if you submit as an answer I will accept it)

Comment: The underlying problem may be that all the files are marked as executables. `ls -l *.js` will show you that. If you mark them as not executable, say with `chmod -x *.js` you won't need to change the Dolphin preferences.

Comment: I don't understand why `.js` files are treated as executables by default to begin with. I don't recall ever having this issue with Linux Mint and others, but maybe I just didn't notice.